# I am not able to create my react application on npm

Tags: npm, create-react-app

```
$ npx create-react-app application
```

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\snigdha'
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
>       at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
>       at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:77:20
>       at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
>       at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
>       at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20) C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98   var
>   doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
>                             ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
>       at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
>       at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
>       at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27) Install for create-react-app@latest failed with code 7

Comment: `Cannot read property` error codes usually involve Administrator privileges issues. Try `Run as Administrator` your terminal or command prompt or also you can change your global `prefix` to disk `D:` i.e.

Comment: So did it work? If so, notify me so I post an answer and then we close this issue

Comment: I just tried it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your cache with

```
npm cache clean
```